# Spring Loadbalancer Configuration without a discovery server

Tags: spring, load-balancing, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I am currently working on a POC about client side load balancing.

I thought to use Spring Cloud Loadbalancer for that. But unlike Netflix Ribbon, I could not find a way to configure Spring Cloud Loadbalancer to work without a discovery server such as Eureka.

Please could you let me know if there is a way to configure it to work without a discovery server (just by giving a list of ip addresses) .

Thanks

Comment: Yes, by setting values in `spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances`. Will look for a sample.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/ce3b19b428e489fa54fa2b684a31e7b740829719/spring-cloud-commons/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientPropertiesMappingTests.java#L40-L44

Comment: You might also want to read up on https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/2.2.x/reference/html/#instance-health-check-for-loadbalancer for this usecase.

Comment: I tried didn't work, got No such host is known

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj, Any thing worked for you?

Comment: I was successful by following the comments of @spencergibb

Comment: @SAtahAhmedKhan - I ended up hard-coding hostname when testing without Eureka.

Comment: @tnishada - A minimal example in github can be very useful.